# Copy row from non active sheet and past on non active sheet on next available row?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following macro to copy a range of rows from my non active worksheet in the background and paste it also on the non active worksheet on the next available row.

For some reason I am getting the error object doesn't support this property or method, runtime error 438.

```
Sub Save8()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set NextRow = Range("B" & Sheets("Time Allocation").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
Sheets("Time Allocation").Range("B506:L515").Copy
Sheets("Time Allocation").NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=1, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set NextRow = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The part of the code giving the error is:

```
Sheets("Time Allocation").NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=1, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

however if I use the below code it works fine and pastes it onto the specified range, however I can't use this because I intend to have multiple copies and pastes of the same range of rows going down the page onto the next available rows:

```
Sub Save8()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set NextRow = Range("B" & Sheets("Time Allocation").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
Sheets("Time Allocation").Range("B506:L515").Copy
Sheets("Time Allocation").Range("B516").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set NextRow = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What part of the code is giving you the error? I suspect it is here: Sheets("Time Allocation").NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=1, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: @ClintStreet yes that's correct, see updated answer

Comment: Basic debugging & troubleshooting tip: break your statement down into multiple statements, connected by variables.  `Set aSheet = Sheets("Time Allocation")`, then `Set aRow = aSheet.NextRow` ...  when you break it down like that you'll get more insight into the error.

Comment: Where do you want the copied data to go into the active sheet or into the "Time Allocation" sheet? Right now it is going into the active sheet because you didn't properly set the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell this is what you need, not sure what you are using it for as the UsedRange will keep resizing the range but you are not copying using the object so you will get a duplicated copy happening. Here is my code for you:

```
Dim NextRow As Range
Sub Save8()
Dim sht As Worksheet, currentRow As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set sht = Sheets("Time Allocation")
Set currentRow = sht.Range(sht.UsedRange.Address)
Set NextRow = currentRow.Offset(currentRow.Rows.Count, 0)

Sheets("Time Allocation").Range("B506:L515").Copy
'NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=1, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
NextRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set NextRow = Nothing
Set currentRow = Nothing
Set sht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Because here

```
Sheets("Time Allocation").NextRow.PasteSpecial (etc ...)
```

you are telling Excel to look for a property `NextRow` on the `Worksheet Object` , property that doesn't exist.

Instead , simply call the `PasteSpecial` method like this:

```
NextRow.PasteSpecial (etc ...)
```

and it will work.

Comment: Only problem is next row is not the row after his range that he has specified because he has not set next row properly.

Comment: Uhmm you can use that syntax anyway if you know your data upon, (i.e. , you know it start from the first row and you just add one statically) on top of the userange.rows.count. you Solution works keeping any offset from the top in account, so he can combine both like this:

Comment: @Clint Street: I apologize , I'm new to So and i didn't know i can't edit a comment for more than 5 minutes, and i also didn't saw your answer (i was just answering his question) .  Both snippets works, you also added the dynamic offset

Comment: No worries I also found out the hard way no edits after 5 minutes.